# XE ucs package events

Tags: sql-server, connectivity, extended-events, trace

Can anybody explain for what purposes exists ucs package {C0AB75C5-B1EA-445B-B7DF-F897686F94E7} "Extended events for Unified Communications Stack"

I have tried to catch some events like ucs_connection_recv_io, usc_connection_setup but always events session is empty.

What conditions/settings/etc need to events start captured?

Answer (score 2):

> Can anybody explain for what purposes exists ucs package {C0AB75C5-B1EA-445B-B7DF-F897686F94E7} "Extended events for Unified Communications Stack"

It's to capture events that occur in the UCS stack :)

> What conditions/settings/etc need to events start captured?

First, you'll need to be utilizing something which uses UCS.

### What is UCS?

The Unified Communications Stack, or UCS, is a kind of next progression or evolution of the service broker infrastructure which is more of a built upon advancement than a replacement. In fact, you have no choice in the matter. This means things like service broker endpoints which include items such as database mirroring (deprecated since 2012) and availability groups. If you're not using any endpoints that utilize this, you're not going to see any events.

### Are Any of the XE Helpful?

To most people, nothing in there will be that useful. There are some that can be used to understand certain behaviors, such as checking to see if the endpoints truly are stuck (though there are easier ways of verifying traffic), but most will be utterly useless.

I'm not saying don't play around with it, feel free to do so, just don't expect to get anything helpful out of it. I've used many of these events as they are helpful in troubleshooting extremely narrow and specific issues with the UCS stack, or to verify that no issues exist at this level of the communications heirarchy.

That being said, there are events that have no other correlating event, such as marrying up the sent vs receive data, which is better off done at the network tcp packet level than with XE.

Comment: Thank you! Finally found some information abous this :)